# Unable to run Abp framework Angular project

Tags: angular, yarnpkg, abp

I created a new solution using the following abp cli command:

abp new MyProject.Cloud -u angular --theme basic

The aspnetcore solution builds just fine and I have setup the database etc but I cant get the angular solution to build? I have run Yarn, then Yarn Start but I get the following error:

```
[error] Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, lstat 'E:\Repositories\abpTest\angular\node_modules\@volo'
    at Object.realpathSync (node:fs:2552:7)
    at resolveGlobalStyles (E:\Repositories\abpTest\angular\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-angular\src\webpack\configs\styles.js:64:33)
    at getStylesConfig (E:\Repositories\abpTest\angular\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-angular\src\webpack\configs\styles.js:97:70)
    at E:\Repositories\abpTest\angular\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-angular\src\builders\dev-server\index.js:144:43
    at E:\Repositories\abpTest\angular\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-angular\src\utils\webpack-browser-config.js:75:16
    at generateWebpackConfig (E:\Repositories\abpTest\angular\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-angular\src\utils\webpack-browser-config.js:64:40)
    at async generateBrowserWebpackConfigFromContext (E:\Repositories\abpTest\angular\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-angular\src\utils\webpack-browser-config.js:125:20)
    at async generateI18nBrowserWebpackConfigFromContext (E:\Repositories\abpTest\angular\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-angular\src\utils\webpack-browser-config.js:73:20)
    at async setup (E:\Repositories\abpTest\angular\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-angular\src\builders\dev-server\index.js:141:47)
```

The @volo folder does not exist in my node_modules folder but it does in the solution i created using the Commercial trial i had. I have used abp cli to logout from my account and also tried clean etc but I just cant get it working? Am i barking up the wrong tree or have I missed something?

- **Edit** *
  I have tried running it on my laptop too which has never had Abp Commercial on it so it must be to do with the basic theme?

Comment: Can you run the `abp install-libs` command on terminal?

Comment: Thanks, yes I had tried running that but I tried it again just incase but no luck. Still the same error. I think it is to do with the Basic template being used instead of the lepton one. I would prefer to use the Basic one though as I want to implement my own theme